# Powershell replace file content with output of previous command

Tags: windows, powershell, jq

In a directory i have few hundred json files. Each file has a json property called qlist that i want to remove from that file.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "...path...\*.json"
foreach($file in $files)
{
    .\jq.exe 'del(.qlist)' $file | Out-File -FilePath $file
}
```

the jq part works fine, but i cannot figure out how to write output of jq into a file, code above prunes all json files for me.

For example if i would be on a llinux os would simply do

```
./jq 'del(.qlist)' $file > $file
```

Comment: reading and writing a file in the same pipeline will result into a blank file, you need to first read, close the stream and then write to it. so, essentially, use the grouping operator `(...)`: `(.\jq.exe 'del(.qlist)' $file) | Set-Content $file`

Comment: As an aside: The Linux command you're showing would result in the very same problem: `$file` would get _truncated_ (reset to a zero-byte file) _before_ `jq` gets invoked.